# Activar botones de mantenimiento para todas mis vistas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estoy trabajando con WPF, Visual Studio 2015

- Tengo una vista principal que es mi vista de inicio, en el cual cae un TabControl y sus respectivos TabItem en tiempo de ejecución.
- En los TabItem al momento de activarlos(hacer click) llama a su respectivo UserControl que hace la vez de otra vista donde están todos los controles.
- Entonces la secuencia es **Vista principal** -> **TabControl(UserControl)** -> **Vistas**(UserControl[donde tengo los controles para ingresar información a la app como mostrar también]).

La referencia para poder crear esa técnica de llamar vistas la tome de acá [Using ContentTemplateSelector in Tab Control View](https://jacobaloysious.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/mvvm-using-contenttemplateselector-in-tab-control-view/)

[image: Vista principal]

El tema es que cuando el UserControl por ejemplo llamado usrUsuario entre al tabUsuario comprobar que este dentro del tab para cuando haga clic en cualquier botón del mantenimiento haga la comprobación que hay un usrControl si lo hay se ejecuta el evento Guardar que esta en el usrControl.

Para eso he creado un interfaz que implemento en todos los user que tenga que hacer los mantenimientos.

```
public interface ICommandAction
{
    void Nuevo();
    void Guardar();
    void Eliminar();
}
```

Hasta ahí ya tengo los eventos de cada vista(usr)

```
public partial class UsuarioView : UserControl, ICommandAction
{
    public UsuarioView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Eliminar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Guardar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Nuevo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}
```

Ahora el tema es comprobar si hay un usr(UserControl) dentro de un tab y comunicárselo a la View principal que recibe al TabControl y este a las view(usr) que entran en cada Tab.

- Lo primero decidí trabajar en el usrTabControl el cual recibe a las views, para validar si tiene una view dentro del tab.

  ```
  public void Guardar()
  {
      if (_myTabItemModel.CurrentMyTabContentViewModel != null)
          _eventHub.Publish(new ActionBotonMenu { Flag = true });
  }
  ```
- Y esa información enviarlo al View principal por medio de eventos, pero el tema es que no llamo a ninguno de estos usr que caen en el me refiero que no hago `usrUsuario usr = new usrUsuario(); usr.Show();`

El tema es un poco extenso, espero haberme explicado, ¿Cómo podría validar desde el View principal que en el usrTabControl hay un usrUsuario o el que estuviese activo para poder mandar a registrar info cuando hagan click en botón Guardar?

Comment: A ver, imaginemos que cada TabItem tiene un nombre asignado, por ejemplo el que dice "Lista" se llama "tabLista", entonces desde la vista principal puedes saber si tiene algo dentro así:

bool contiene = tabLista.Content != null;

Con eso ya sabes si tiene algo, puedes saber si tiene un tipo de objeto específico comparándolo así:

if(tab1.Content.GetType() == typeof(UserControl))
            {
                //tiene un UserControl
            }
            else
            {
                //No tiene un UserControl, pero puede tener otra cosa
            }  y eso sería.

Answer (score 1):

Así puedes saber si tu TabItem (imaginemos que se llama tabLista) tiene algo dentro, en este caso un UsrControl:

```
if (tabLista.Content != null) //si tiene algo
{
    //El tabItem tiene algo
    if (tabLista.Content.GetType() == typeof(UsrControl))
    {
        //tiene un UsrControl
    }
    else
    {
        //No tiene un UserControl, pero tiene otra cosa
    }
}
else
{
    //El tabItem no tiene nada de nada 
}
```

Está un poco confusa la pregunta pero creo que esto te puede ayudar.

Ahora, si quieres saber si tu TabControl tiene TabItems con un ciclo for se puede

```
for (int i = 0; i < control.Items.Count; i++)
{
    TabItem tab = (TabItem)control.Items[i];
    //if(tab.Content != null)
    //{
        //    //etc......
    //}
}
```

Y con eso puedes consultar lo que tiene cada Tab, su propiedad Visibility, IsEnabled, etc.
Un saludo.